# How to change electron-builder path for portable application on windows?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

We would love to set a static path for the electron-builder portable application on Windows. To be more specific, instead of generating a random folder name in TEMP/someRandomName, we would like to have the same path every time e.g. TEMP/app-name-portable.

We've tried setting the PORTABLE_EXECUTABLE_DIR in our package.json scripts to a new path, but no luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed for us and the discussion and the implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/3799).